# Fetch data in database table insert it if not exist else return the row id

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table file witch contain a column date_file_creation,I would like to create a table date contain the date file creation, when I insert a new file I check the table date if it exist I return the row id and insert it as a foreign key in the table file , else I insert a new date and get its new row id to insert it in the table file. how can I do this?

this is my attemp: first I create a function findfile to check if the date exist or not

```
public int finddate(String date){
    AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_DATE + " where COLUMN_NAME_DATE = date", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor != null ) {
        if  (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
          int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
          return id;
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } 
    }
        return 0;

    }
```

then on the `onCreate` I do that

```
if( resultat==0)
        {
        Filedate date1=new Filedate();
        date1.setfileDate(providedFileDate);
        filedateArrayList.add(date1);
        insertDate(date1);//insert in table date
        newid=finddate(providedFileDate);//get the row id of the new date inserting
        }
        else
            {newid=resultat; //the row id =the result reterned by the finfdate method}
```

then i insert it in the file table

this is myDbhelper

```
public class AndroidOpenDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database attributes
public static final String DB_NAME = "file_db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

//  file Table attributes
public static final String TABLE_FILE = "file_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME = "file_name_column";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY = "file_category_column";
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME= "file_theme_column";
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING = "file_date_creating_column";
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_CLOUD = "file_cloud_column";
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_UPLOADING = "file_date_upload_column";
//category table
public static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "category_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY = "category_column";
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY_ABREVIATION = "abreviation_column";
//theme table
public static final String TABLE_THEME = "theme_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_THEME = "theme_column";  
public static final String COLLUMN_NAME_THEME_ABREVIATION = "abreviation_column";
//date table
public static final String TABLE_DATE = "date_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date_column";    


public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    // create category table
    String sqlQueryToCreateCategoryTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY + " text not null, "
            + COLLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY_ABREVIATION + " text not null);";
    db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateCategoryTable);
    //create theme table
    String sqlQueryToCreateThemeTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_THEME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + COLUMN_NAME_THEME + " text not null, "
            + COLLUMN_NAME_THEME_ABREVIATION + " text not null);";

    db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateThemeTable);
    //table date creation
    String sqlQueryToCreateDateTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_DATE + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " text not null);";
    db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateDateTable);
            //Because this method get executed every time we created an object of this class. 
            //"create table if not exists TABLE_NAME ( BaseColumns._ID integer primary key autoincrement, FIRST_COLUMN_NAME text not null, SECOND_COLUMN_NAME integer not null);"
    String sqlQueryToCreateFileTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_FILE + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                                    + COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME + " text not null, "
                                                                    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CATEGORY+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
                                                                    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_THEME+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
                                                                    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING +") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DATE+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
                                                                    + COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_CLOUD + " text default null,"
                                                                    + COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_UPLOADING + " text default null);";
            db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateFileTable);



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
        // Upgrade the database
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to ask for a better approach? Coz you already implement to get the id of the row that was inserted. I don't understand your question clearly.

Comment: Is resultat a global variable in your activity? Coz if it is then it will always be zero? I don't understand how resultat will never be zero as you are having this code in your onCreate.

Comment: yes it is,I will change it, I can't have any result of my code because I can't create the date table ,I have this error on logcat// 06-15 05:18:55.947: E/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 05:18:55.947: E/AndroidRuntime(354): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: date_table: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM date_table where COLUMN_NAME_DATE = date //my table date and table file are empty at the begining

Comment: You need to post your dbhelper class, obviously something is going wrong there and it's not creating the tables you think it is.

Comment: is something  wrong or missing in my code?, because the table exist and the column also but I still have this 06-15 05:56:18.547: E/AndroidRuntime(7541): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COLUMN_NAME_DATE: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM date_table where COLUMN_NAME_DATE = date

Comment: the date table now is creating but whey it does'nt found the column?

Comment: please post the DB helper class and also show us how are you creating your table or else we can't help you.

Comment: I add my Db helper class

Comment: I need your heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp

Answer (score 0):

If you made changes to you database then the table might not yet exist. I had the same issues with my database. When it has the same name and same version it does not create a new working version of the database even if you make changes by adding tables.

You have to either change the version number and use the update database function or blow away your current database so that you can get the new working version.

Check to see if you database currently has a data_table created. You can do this by running "adb shell" in the command line. Finding your database and running sqlite3 [database name]. Once in there you can find out what tables are there by typing ".table". If data_table does not show up then it has not been created in the database.

---

I did some more looking at your code. I do not think you file_data table was being built correctly. I made some changes to the SQL statement that you use to exicute it and was finaly able to build the database. See if this helps.

```
String sqlQueryToCreateFileTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_FILE + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME + " text not null, " + COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME + " text not null,  " + COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING + " text not null, "+ COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY + " text not null, "
    + COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_CLOUD + " text not null, "+ COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_UPLOADING + " text default null, FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CATEGORY+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_THEME+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING +") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DATE+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"));";
```

Put it in you AndroidOpenDbHelper. You also might have to blow away your database to make sure that the new database is created. The database onCreate() will only run if there is not a database with the same name and version. If a database exists with the same version and name it will not create another copy of the database.

---

Also I just noticed that you are trying to search for date in the wrong way. you will need to write something like this.

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_DATE + " where " + AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + "= '" + date + "';", null);
```

Otherwise your query is just searching the COLUMN_NAME_DATE for an instance of the string date and trying to compare it to a column in the date_file table. Your current SQL statement is saying find the rows where the value in the hypothetical "data" column is equal to the value in the "COLUMN_NAME_DATE".

Variables that are added to an SQL statement need to be added inside quotes. 
`"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + VALUE_NAME + "';"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: tabe is created but when i try to add a new table to my database,i  have this : sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: file_table,how can I update my database