# fetch if data exist in database table

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch data in database table insert it if not exist else return the row id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044931/fetch-data-in-database-table-insert-it-if-not-exist-else-return-the-row-id)

I try to fetch if data exist in database table, if yes I should get the row id else I insert it in the table this my code

```
public int finddate(String date){
    int id=0;
    AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + 
                            AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_DATE + " where " +
                            AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " = " + date,
                            null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor != null) { 
        if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        }
    } else { 
        id=0;
    }
    sqliteDatabase.close(); 
    return id;          
}
```

when i try with an existing item I get the result of this method =0 and the item is inserted in the table,
how can I do this?

Comment: shouldnt date be given in single quotes (') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` is not being correctly escaped. The safest and cleanest way to resolve it is to pass the date value as a parameter, rather than embedding it in the query.

You can also tidy up the cursor management quite a bit. You don't need to check for a `null` cursor, as an exception will be thrown if the query fails. Also, you don't need to set `id = 0` as you've already done that at the start. This is much simpler:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + 
                        AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_DATE + " where " +
                        AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " = ?",
                        new String[] { date } );

if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
    id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}

cursor.close();
sqliteDatabase.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_DATE + " where "+ AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DATE+ " =\'"+date+"\'", null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
cursor.moveTofirst();

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) { 

        id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    }
} else { 
    id=0;
}
```